# ftp_get() expects parameter 2 to be a valid path, resource given

Tags: php

Why am I receiving this error?  According to the [ftp_get docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php), the function is defined like so:

```
bool ftp_fget ( resource $ftp_stream , resource $handle , string $remote_file , int $mode [, int $resumepos = 0 ] )
```

However, when I pass this function a file resource, I receive the error:

```
ftp_get() expects parameter 2 to be a valid path, resource given
```

Here is my code:

```
$ftp = ftp_connect(FTP_HOST);

if (ftp_login($ftp, FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD)) {
    $file = tmpfile();

    if(ftp_get($ftp, $file, FTP_FILENAME, FTP_ASCII)) {
        file_get_contents($file);
    }
}
```

Why is the error suggesting that the function expects a path, when the docs show it defined as expecting a resource? I am using PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: Your link is wrong. It's for ftp_fget()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use the doc of ftp_fget instead of ftp_get:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

```
bool ftp_get ( resource $ftp_stream , string $local_file , string $remote_file , int $mode [, int $resumepos = 0 ] )
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I changed it to use `ftp_fget`, which is what I intended.